# Regex to match words comma separated, multiplelines and between two strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to get the following words (in bold) using JavaScript/jquery:

Blablablalblabla

- Blablablalblabla: Blablablalblabla
- Affected: **Windows Vista, Windows 7**
- hxxps://Blablablalblabla

Blablablalblabla

- Affected: **Windows Vista , Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 
  8.1, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 10, Windows Server 2016**
- hxxps://Blablablalblabla

They are comma separated. Their appear after the string 'Affected:' and ends with the string '- https'.

So far I have tryied several regex, for example: **/Affected(.*?)\n- https/g**

Maybe I'm focusing worthly... any idea?

Comment: What about `/Affected:\s*([^]*?)\n- https/g`? See https://regex101.com/r/GVEqVI/3. I guess you replaced `http` with `hxxp` so as not to create links in the post, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a `[^]` or `[\s\S]` construct to match any character, and include `:` and a space into the pattern.

```js
var rx = /Affected:\s*([^]*?)\n- https/g;
var str = "Blablablalblabla  \n\n- Blablablalblabla: Blablablalblabla\n- Affected: **Windows Vista, Windows 7** \n- https://Blablablalblabla\n\n\nBlablablalblabla";
var m, res=[];
while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1].trim());
}
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!